# Android studio 3 forcing me to create project with API 26

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a project with min sdk 18 and target 21. When I initially create a project a select the minimum SDK as 18 however it gives me no option to target 21 and gives me 26 by default. It's giving me a number of features that aren't supported in 18/26 such as android:roundIcon in the manifest and some drawables that I'm having trouble removing without getting errors. I've tried setting the min and target sdk in the build.gradle and then rebuilding the project as well as 'Sync project with gradle files'

EDIT: After deleting the 'mitmap' directory it seemed to resolve the problem but I'm wondering if I should even be deleting this?

Comment: add your build.gradle. and gradle plugin version .

Answer (score 0):

Some features are removed (deprecated) in newer API levels, and some features are added or replaced. Generally, you can set your minimum SDK to a low API for example to 15 but if you initially created the project with higher minimum, Android studio gets excited and tries to implement the new stuff, later when you change your mind and specify low API it complains "*I thought you wanted the new stuff :(*" says the studio.
So you will need to do some refactoring in that case to your code like you just did.

Same applies to existing projects that target minimum API of +21.
When you change it to lower minimum API level things will turn red and it will most likely ask you to do a lot of `if/else` checking to existing code for API level for some features that work on certain API levels.

I hope that helps.